# Entering ubuntu without Nvidia graphic card drivers

Tags: boot, nvidia, graphics

I have an old vaio with win 7 and ubuntu 14.04, with a NVIDIA Geforce 8400M.
Now the screen is a mess with squares and lines both in ubuntu and windows. I think the graphic card is broken.

By entering in windows safe mode I was able to unistall Nvidia drivers and now I can enter windows without any problems (I think due to the use of the native intel graphic card).
I want to do a similar thing for ubuntu. What can I do in order to use ubuntu without the nvidia graphic card?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Sounds like science fiction. If the graphics card doesn't work, what do you connect the monitor to?

Comment: I use it with the Nvidia drivers disabled, and it works using just the native intel graphic card I think

Answer (score 1):

Ok I've found a way.
First I've tried the first solution from [this topic](https://askubuntu.com/questions/31180/how-to-get-disable-nvidia-graphics-card-which-has-recently-expired-so-that-i-c?rq=1) without success. Then I've tried [this other](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206283/how-can-i-uninstall-a-nvidia-driver-completely) solution but I've had problems with apt-get due to impossibility to writing in /var/cache/apt/.

In the end I mixed the two solutions. In summary:

Boot with a LiveCD

Mount Ubuntu root partition, change XY accordingly:

```
sudo mount /dev/sdXY /mnt
```

Mount some partitions:

```
sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
```

Change root directory to the mounted Ubuntu partition:

```
sudo chroot /mnt
```

Last, from the 2nd link, remove nvidia drivers:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia-*
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf
echo 'nouveau' | sudo tee -a /etc/modules
```

This works great for me, Ubuntu works perfect with low impact on graphics